# Windows does not open my SATA HDD when connected with USB

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata, sata-to-usb

I changed PC recently. I had 2TB Seagate SATA drive that I connected with USB to my PC.
MyPc doesn't show it at all, and the COMPUTER MANAGEMENT only shows this - changing the disk letter doesn't change anything. The files are not being shown. In device manager the disk is shown as ASM105x. I have Win10.

PS. I just tried SeaTools app and it doesn't show the drive either.

[image]

how it looks in devices&printers

in disk partition it is showing as under E: letter and 0B NO MEDIA.

Comment: Removable drives are shown in the My Computer in a separate group (if grouping is enabled). Such groups can be collapsed so that the removable drives are not shown. use the tree view on the left side to check if the drive is really missing.

Comment: I know that, the drive is not displayed there. As stated above, it is only showing in DP or in ''devices & printers'' as ASM105x - I just added 2 pics FYI

Comment: I figured it out. Need external power supply cable :/ Facepalm